# how to print if statements on same lines

Tags: python

im trying to get a result that will look like this

```
### ###
#2# #3#
### ###
```

```
first = 2
second = 3
if first == 2:
  print('###', end=" ")
  print('#2#', end=" ")
  print('###', end=" ")
if second == 3:
  print('###', end=" ")
  print('#3#', end=" ")
  print('###', end=" ")
```

i cannot get them to go next to each other like i want, this also goes for numbers 1 through 11 so i cannot just do `if first == 2 and second == 3:` that would be way too many lines

Comment: You want to print the numbers from 1 to 11 with hashes around it ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad :(

Comment: the variables will be random 1-11 and i want it to print the numbers next to each other with the hashes around them

Answer (score 2):

You can use for-loops for the task:

```
first = 2
second = 3

for current in range(first, second+1):
    print('###', end=' ')
print()
for current in range(first, second+1):
    print('#{}#'.format(current), end=' ')
print()
for current in range(first, second+1):
    print('###', end=' ')
print()
```

Prints:

```
### ### 
#2# #3# 
### ###
```

---

For:

```
first = 2
second = 6
```

it prints:

```
### ### ### ### ### 
#2# #3# #4# #5# #6# 
### ### ### ### ###
```

---

EDIT: To print only two numbers:

```
first = 2
second = 6

print('### ###')
print('#{}# #{}#'.format(first, second))
print('### ###')
```

Prints:

```
### ###
#2# #6#
### ###
```

Comment: Could i do this but if first = 1 and second = 6 it doesn't print everything in-between?

Comment: that still prints everything in-between 1 and 6 though

Answer (score 0):

A more compact, readable and maintainable option:

```
first = 2
second = 7

def doLine(s):
    for i in range(first, second+1):
        print(s.format(i), end=' ')
    print()

doLine('###')
doLine('#{}#')
doLine('###')
```

Result:

```
### ### ### ### ### ### 
#2# #3# #4# #5# #6# #7# 
### ### ### ### ### ###
```